# Overwrite file content linux system call

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am able to append one file content to other using O_APPEND flag in "open" system call. but struggling a lot to overwrite the existing content.when I try opening the file with just O_WRONLY with out any flags its not overwriting the existing content. Can some please hep me in this?

Answer (score 3):

Either add O_TRUNC (if you want to toss out all of the previous stuff), or seek the fd to 0 (if you want to "insert" over it, like an insert cursor).  Be aware that you might not be able to see changes immediately - that's because of buffered I/O.  You can use O_SYNC to make sure every write is flushed through.  (Probably don't do that though.)

Comment: Any buffering done by `write()` is transparent (except on some network file systems).

Comment: There are a number of situations where it might not be transparent, NFS is notoriously one.  Hence the "might not be able to see..."